# How to access files on Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

I am in a critical condition.  I was paying a developer in India who left the project but now I need to access the php pages.

I have explored the joomla site using the admin login but i can't find how he is displaying the html/php pages.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're looking for the front-end template for the website.

Using FTP or whatever control panel go to the Joomla folder, look for a folder called `templates` - it should be one of the folders in there.

To check what the name of the current template is, go to the admin panel and look in the template menu.

If your developer has also made any custom components, the front-end part would be somewhere in the `components` folder, and the backend bit would be in `administrator->components`.

Comment: i am super admin but i can't see where it says admin panel ---> templates

Comment: and it seems ftp hasn't been enabled.  how do i set it up?

Comment: when you say "admin login" do you mean via http://yoursite.com/administrator ? or something like http://cpanel.yoursite.com

Comment: domain.com/administrator is what i was able t use

Comment: In domain.com/administrator, look at Extensions from the top menu, and pick Template manager. About FTP, your best bet is talking to your host.

Also, I really recommend reading Brent Friar's comment if you haven't. Templates are the most obvious way to affect a website's front-end look but there can be a lot more involved too.

Comment: Thanks i was able to get into FTP but it still as confusing as it was before.  I still can't see how the developer is calling those pages and i can't find those pages!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to read some Joomla tutorials. There are many places that can be used to "display the html/php".

First you have the template files that determine how the site looks and what module positions are available to be used. Generally there is one template in use but there can be multiples.

Next you will have components where the content is entered. At a minimum it is likely that you are using the com_content (articles/categories) and it is very likely there are others being used.

You will also have various modules that will display content in areas outside of the main content area. This will generally include menus, login forms, and other similar content.

Last, plugins can also have an effect on the content. In some cases plugins inject content and in others they replace placeholders with content.

There are a lot of pieces to the puzzle that all come together to display the resulting web page, it's not just a simple question of accessing some files.

Comment: THanks.  I was able to get into FTP but i can't see the files that the developer used to call in.  Like the links are something like: domain.com/index.php/home domain.com/index.php/about but in ftp i can't find those files.

Comment: Those files don't exists. There is only one "file" in Joomla - templates/CURRENT_TEMPLATE/index.php. That file is used to build each page within the site based on what you are clicking on. It's not going to do you any good to touch that file as it only defines the locations of the content. The content is contained within the various extensions as I mentioned in my answer. You need to login to the admin if you want to change content, not edit PHP files.